# Composing Rails Layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Assuming I have:

```
# layouts/application.html.erb

<html>
  <head>
    <body>
      <p>Hi</p>
      <%= yield :toolbar1 %>
      <%= yield :toolbar2 %>
      <%= yield %>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

And two additional layouts depending on the circumstance:

```
# layouts/toolbar1.html.erb
<% content_for :toolbar1 do %>
  <p>toolbar1</p>
<% end %>

# layouts/toolbar2.html.erb
<% content_for :toolbar2 do %>
  <p>toolbar2</p>
<% end %>
```

How can I conditionally load `:toolbar1` and `toolbar2` on a per-controller basis, for instance:

```
# Controller where *only* :toolbar1 should be present on show action
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render "show", layout: "toolbar1"
  end
end
```

...does not work, because it just tries to load `toolbar1.html.erb` without loading the `application.html.erb` layout. Basically I want to compose layouts controller by controller (route by route if you prefer).

Comment: `content_for :toolbar1` has to go into the "show" template for it to work. but it looks like you want to just `render` a toolbar, not yield.

Comment: Well, the way I understand layouts conceptually is that they normally wrap the main content of whatever you're showing, it feels like you should be able to do smth like this and compose them instead of conditionally rendering them in multiple `show` templates. I understand what I have above doesn't work, but is there a way to do what I'm suggesting, namely compose layouts based on routes/controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably better ways to do what you need to do.

But it is doable:

```
# layouts/toolbar1.html.erb

<% content_for :toolbar1 do %>
  <p>toolbar1</p>
<% end %>

<%= render template: "layouts/application" %>
```

The rest is the same.

*https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts*

---

As alternative, template inheritance could be useful for this:

```rb
# app/views/application/_toolbar.html.erb

# empty
```

```html
<!-- layouts/application.html.erb -->

<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <%= render "toolbar" %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then override `_toolbar` partial:

```html
<!-- app/views/*/_toolbar.html.erb -->

<div>a toolbar for some controller</div>
```

*https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#template-inheritance*